# Discord Bot : Add roles from a JSON file

Tags: json, discord, discord.js

I would like to add or remove Reaction Roles from a JSON file on Discord. I would like that when a user clicks on the emoji, the corresponding role is added from a JSON file that links the role and the emoji.

For the moment my code works but it's not clean.

Here is my code :

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });
const { token }  = require('./config.json');
const Roles = require('/roles.json');

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot opérationnel");
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'Choisir un rôle :') {
        const reactionEmoji1 = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'FR');
        const reactionEmoji2 = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'UK');
        message.react(reactionEmoji1);
        message.react(reactionEmoji2);
    }
});


client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
    if(user.bot) return;

    console.log("Réaction ajoutée");

    if(reaction.message.id === "1037314191163412573"){
        if(reaction.emoji.name === "FR"){
            var member =  reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id); // Va récuperer le membre du serveur 
            member.roles.add("1036583426620399647").then (mbr => { // Assigne le role
            console.log("Role attribué avec succès pour" + mbr.displayName);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Le role n'a pas pu etre attribué :" + err);
        });
        }
        if(reaction.emoji.name === "UK"){
            var member =  reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id); // Va récuperer le membre du serveur 
            member.roles.add("1036583684247134208").then (mbr => { // Assigne le role
            console.log("Role attribué avec succès pour" + mbr.displayName);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Le role n'a pas pu etre attribué :" + err);
        });
        }
    }
});

client.on("messageReactionRemove", (reaction, user) => {
    if(user.bot) return;

    console.log("Réaction supprimée");

    if(reaction.message.id === "1037314191163412573"){
        if(reaction.emoji.name === "FR"){
            var member =  reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id); // Va récuperer le membre du serveur 
            member.roles.remove("1036583426620399647").then (mbr => { // Assigne le role
            console.log("Role supprimé avec succès pour" + mbr.displayName);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Le role n'a pas pu etre attribué :" + err);
        });
        }
        if(reaction.emoji.name === "UK"){
            var member =  reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id); // Va récuperer le membre du serveur 
            member.roles.remove("1036583684247134208").then (mbr => { // Assigne le role
            console.log("Role supprimé avec succès pour" + mbr.displayName);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Le role n'a pas pu etre attribué :" + err);
        });
        }
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

And here is the JSON file :

```json
{
    "message": "1037314191163412573",
    "channel": "1037311658416152616",
    "reactions": [
        {
            "emoji": "FR",
            "role": "1036583426620399647"               
        },
        {
            "emoji": "UK",
            "role": "1036583684247134208"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to improve upon? Do you just want your code cleaned up?

Comment: I would like the code to look in the JSON file and then attribute the role. For now, it only works with the emojis I specified (FR and UK)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly checking each emoji with an if statement, you could loop through each value in the object and check every emoji you have stored.

This should work if you add more emojis to you object, as long as its structure is consistent.

Example:

```js
// assuming `data` is your object
for(r of data.reactions) {
    if(reaction.emoji.name === r.emoji) {
        let member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id)
        member.roles.add(r.role).then(() => {
            // etc
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but now my code doesn't get into the "if"

Comment: let member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id)
    for (r of role_list) {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === r.emoji) {
            console.log("Emoji associé");
            member.roles.add(r.role).then(() => {
            // etc
        })
    }
} ```

Answer (score 0):

Voici le code qui fonctionne :

````
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
    if (user.bot) return;

    if (reaction.message.id === role_list.message) {
        let member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);
        for (let i = 0; i < role_list.reactions.length; i++) {
            let r = role_list.reactions[i];
            if (reaction.emoji.name === r.emoji) {
                member.roles.add(r.role).then(mbr => {
                    console.log("Role attribué avec succès pour " + mbr.displayName);
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log("Le role n'a pas pu etre attribué :" + err);
                });
            }
        }
        
    }

});```
````